# wrong resault in php

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to catch two variable `($phone,$key)` and if `$key` exists in the random table from the first DB then check if &phone exists in users table in second DB return id else if doesn't exist make a row and then echo id. here is my code.where is my problem?

```
$Key = $_GET['key'];
$phone = $_GET['phone'];
$dublicate = "SELECT id,phone FROM  users WHERE phone = $phone;";
$valid = "SELECT id,phone,random FROM random WHERE random = $Key;";
$verifyresult=mysqli_query($con,$valid);
$dublicateresult=mysqli_query($con2,$dublicate);

if($verifyresult == true )
{
  if($dublicateresult == true){
   $response=array();
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($dublicateresult)){
    array_push($response,array("id"=>$row[0],"phone"=>$row[1]));
   echo $row[0];

}

 }else{
        $response=array();
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
           array_push($response,array("id"=>$row[0],"phone"=>$row[1],"random"=>$row[2]));
        $result2 = mysqli_query($con2,"INSERT INTO users (phone) 
        VALUES ('$row[1]')");
      $uniq = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE phone = $row[1];";
      $result3=mysqli_query($con2,$uniq);
      if($result3==true){
          $response2=array();
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){
                    array_push($response2,array("id"=>$row[0]));

                   echo $row[0]; 
      }
 }
 }
 }

 }else echo "null";
```

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks! Have a read up on the use of prepared statements with mysqli NEVER trust any user, no matter how well and how much you may trust the user!

Comment: what is the problem? what is it not doing?

Comment: returns are not true